# Problem with conditional required attribute in Angular

Tags: angular

Fairly new to Angular.

I'm trying to mark an input field with an optional "required" attribute, which will be controlled by a property of the same name in the component.

```
@Input() required: boolean = true;
```

Simple, right? That's what I thought.

This is working:

```
<input 
    id="test123" name="test123"
    [required]="required ? '' : null"
    [(ngModel)]="test123"
/>
```

Whereas this is not:

```
<input 
    id="test456" name="test456"
    [required]="required ? '' : null"
  />
```

Obviously, it needs an ngModel for the required to work, but I don't really need a model for this input; I'm just using the input for capturing keyboard events for an auto-complete.

Should I just make a fake model for it in the component? Or is there another way around this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ylufjn

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use `[attr.required]="required || null"` instead of `[required]="required ? '' : null"`

Updated example is here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7dgba?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Better would be to use  `[attr.required]="required ? 'required' : null" `. According to specs values true or false are not allowed in boolean attributes. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute